# Box2D: Using debugdraw in Helloworld.cpp or a similar basic program?

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm trying to create a Box2D program, but I need to enable debugdraw to see what's going on. I was thinking in using the Helloworld program included with the Box2D library as a template. Unfortunately, it doesn't use debugdraw, and I can't seem to be able to implement it. Testbed uses it, but it's a bit convoluted and too poorly explained to be used as a template. So could anyone here share an example of Helloworld.cpp (or a similar basic program that uses Box2D) using debugdraw (preferably implemented like in Testbed)?

I'm using VS2013, if that matters.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't figured this out already (and for future viewers), the core Box2D library does not have a debug drawing feature that can simply be "enabled." It's a physics engine, not a rendering engine.

That said, you don't have to do everything from scratch. The Testbed has an implementation of debug drawing, and you can [make a test](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/making-a-test) that can be run there. Box2D also provides a sort of drawing template, in case you want to implement your own rendering code. Essentially, there are a few callbacks where you can put your code for, say, polygon rendering. Each frame, for each polygon, Box2D will call that callback and your polygon will be rendered on screen!

You asked for a simple example, so here's one using GLFW for windowing and bare-bones OpenGL for what rendering is needed. There are lots of tutorials out there for these, but you don't really need to know anything about them to understand the code.

Main.cpp:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>
#include "Physics.h"

int main() {
    // Initialize window (this is GLFW-specific)
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (!glfwInit()) return 1;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, "Box2D Debug Draw", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return 2;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    DebugDraw debugDraw; // Declare an instance of our DebugDraw class so we can actually use it

    // Set up Box2D world, bodies, etc. (you should be familiar with most of this)
    int velocityIterations = 8;
    int positionIterations = 3;
    b2World* world;
    b2Body* groundBody;
    b2Body* testBody;
    {
        b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);
        world = new b2World(gravity);
        world->SetDebugDraw(&debugDraw); // YOU NEED THIS SO BOX2D KNOWS WHERE TO LOOK FOR DRAWING CALLBACKS
        debugDraw.SetFlags(b2Draw::e_shapeBit);
    }
    {
        b2BodyDef gbDef;
        gbDef.position.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);
        groundBody = world->CreateBody(&gbDef);

        b2PolygonShape gbShape;
        gbShape.SetAsBox(50.0f, 10.0f);

        groundBody->CreateFixture(&gbShape, 0.0f);
    }
    {
        b2BodyDef tbDef;
        tbDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        tbDef.position.Set(0.0f, 10.0f);
        testBody = world->CreateBody(&tbDef);

        b2PolygonShape tbShape;
        tbShape.SetAsBox(1.0f, 1.0f);

        b2FixtureDef tbFix;
        tbFix.shape = &tbShape;
        tbFix.density = 1.0f;
        tbFix.friction = 0.3f;

        testBody->CreateFixture(&tbFix);
    }

    // Loop until user exits
    b2Timer timer;
    float last = timer.GetMilliseconds();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        float now = timer.GetMilliseconds();
        world->Step((now - last) / 1000, 8, 3); // Step simulation forward by amount of time since last step
        last = now;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
        glPushMatrix(); // Push matrix so we can revert after doing some transformations
        glScalef(40.0f / 960.0f, 40.0f / 540.0f, 1.0f); // Zoom out
        glTranslatef(0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f); // Pan up
        world->DrawDebugData(); // CALL THE DRAWING CALLBACKS WE SET UP IN PHYSICS CLASS
        glPopMatrix(); // Revert transformations

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // Push updated buffers to window
        glfwPollEvents(); // Poll user events so OS doesn't think app is frozen
    }

    // Garbage collection
    delete world;
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Physics.h:

```
#ifndef PHYSICS
#define PHYSICS

#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>

class DebugDraw : public b2Draw { // b2Draw has all the virtual functions that we need to override here
public:
    // We won't be implementing all of these, but if we don't declare them here we'll get an override error
    void DrawSolidPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawSolidCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Vec2& axis, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawSegment(const b2Vec2& p1, const b2Vec2& p2, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawTransform(const b2Transform& xf);
};

#endif
```

Physics.cpp:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include "Physics.h"

void DebugDraw::DrawSolidPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color) {
    // Standard OpenGL rendering stuff
    glColor4f(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); 
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
        glVertex2f(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y);
    }
    glEnd();
}

// We just need to have these to prevent override errors, they don't actually do anything right now
void DebugDraw::DrawPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color) {}
void DebugDraw::DrawCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Color& color) {}
void DebugDraw::DrawSolidCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Vec2& axis, const b2Color& color) {}
void DebugDraw::DrawSegment(const b2Vec2& p1, const b2Vec2& p2, const b2Color& color) {}
void DebugDraw::DrawTransform(const b2Transform& xf) {}
```